# How to retry S3 download using Python API

Tags: python, amazon-s3, download, boto

I have a python client to download and extract a file being uploaded at another end. Currently I am using US-east-1. There arose few times where the immediate download failed even though it was uploaded at other end. I searched and found the issue was due to S3's eventual consistency in US-east-1 region.

I would like to know how we can retry S3 get

Comment: S3 now supports read-after-write consistency in all regions, including us-east-1.  So, I don't think the issue is a consistency problem.

Comment: Yes, but they did it by giving a new end point still https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=3112. May be i have to change the end point still, but is there a way to do it from API as well

Comment: You can do "import boto" and then "boto.connect_s3(host='s3-external-1.amazonaws.com')".